# MySQL performance issue, It is working very slow while making a report

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bigdata, accounting

I am working with PHP and MySQL on accounting software
I am having a database of more than 20mb more than 90 table.
I have to create a report making use of more than 70 table at once 
but it's taking too long (more than 10 min)
(there are a lot of queries and I have used summary table also but nothing worked out, I also used async method)
and my server configuration is high
Pls, help me out-

Comment: Adjust your queries. limits the results to be obtained and the columns to be verified, according to specific needs. Evaluate the purchase of a new server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324239/php-mysql-difference-between-buffered-and-unbuffered-queries

Comment: 20 mb is nothing. check indexing on ur tables. try to reduce number of joins

Comment: Note that such a large collection of tables *can* be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: When you are joining a lot of tables in MySQL the optimiser does have a hard time figuring out the right join-order. 70 tables is a lot. An idea could be to use STRAIGHT_JOIN syntax and order the join by yourself.