# Performance fact of using multiple loops(not nested) / single loop for the same dataset

Tags: php, mysql, performance

For exporting data as pdf, i need to query a dataset from the database and then loop through it to manage indexes and then export as pdf. When querying, the dataset can be manipulated in different ways with the use of joins and other mechanism. The confusion is, depending on the structure of the dataset, it can be done within a single loop and it may be done with multiple loops(not nested). What is the performance effect of these two ways.

For example: dataset contains "organizations" and its "inquries"."inquiries" has different types. In this condition, I can query to retrieve dataset as whole and use one loop to go through it or retrieve dataset as sections and then use multiple loops to go through.

What is the performance fact of these two scenarios.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By querying only once per dataset you can bypass the extra latency (as in the time mysql needs to execute its task, if the database is on the local server the additional network latency is very low ofc) that might occure when sending additional queries to the database.

Each time you query the database, the query itself has to be

- send to the databse
- parsed by the database
- analysed and optimised
- executed

and the resultset has to be returned. So performancewise it would be a good idea to reduce any additional runs to the database.

edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215625/3595565 how mysql works

edit2:

I guess it depends on what you want to do with each of those arrays. I probably would treat them seperately, as they all handle different things.

In this scenario performance should not be the important factor as it doesn't matter if you iterate once over an array with 9k elements or iterate 3 times over arrays with 3k elements respectively.

You should set your focus on clear communication via code. Seperate the responsibilities of the entities.

Let's take your example and say for each element in your 3 arrays you want to send an email and all the data needed(from, to, subject etc.) is in your arrays already. Presumption is, the data in the three arrays needs to be treated differently

```
$tableAR = array('Incident' => $incidentAR,
                 'Prevention' => $preventionAR,
                 'Undefined' => $undefinedAR);
foreach($tableAR['Incident'] as $incident){
    sendIncidentmail($incident);
}
// same for prevention and any other array, write your code in a way some random programmer can understand what is happening
```

Of course you could create a function to look into the element, check the type and then decide what kind of mail to send, but it would be a lot less readable at the place of calling the function and the function itself would have to be bigger to decide what it has to with the given data.

```
$tableAR = array('Incident' => $incidentAR,
                 'Prevention' => $preventionAR,
                 'Undefined' => $undefinedAR);
$completeArray = array_merge($tableAR['Incident'], $tableAR['Prevention'], $tableAR['Undefined']);
foreach($completeArray as $element){
    sendMail($incident);
}
```

Comment: this was helpful.but my scenario is not querying different times.the dataset is retrieved once and for all.The confusion is on looping through the retrieved data in order to manage. whether to use single loop for whole dataset or use multiple loops for sections in dataset.Thank you @philipp

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you are doing?

Comment: $tableAR = array('Incident' => $incidentAR,'Prevention' => $preventionAR,'Undefined' => $undefinedAR); Imagine $incidentAR, $preventionAR, and $undefinedAR are arrays within the dataset. The way i queried resulted in this type of dataset. Hence i can loop through each of these sub arrays with seperate loop for each. By the same way i can queried to get dataset as a whole and then use a single loop to go through that. confusion is between these two ways. what is more accurate or both are same? Thanks a lot for your support @Philipp

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer, but it is purely based on opinion. One could profile which is faster, the big loop or some small ones, but the performance would not play that big of a role, imo.